# SoapUI - Hadoop integration

Tags: hadoop, groovy, soapui

Anyone tried integrating SoapUI DB component with Hadoop database? I tried with datasource component and didnt work for me even after adding all the library files inside the lib folder. I have also added the connection string inside the soapui preference section. Finally i had to use groovy script for solving this issue.

> This is how i have integrated now. I have written a groovy script for setting up the hadoop db connection and executing the SQL queries. The problem here is we cannot iterate using SoapUI Loop component here. I have to perform few operations with the retrieved data. So i would like to solve this using the soapui data source component.

Comment: if you are able to connect using hadoop you should be able to connect using datasource step too. Which error are you getting when you try to use datasource step?

Comment: So the error i am getting is SQL syntax exception. But the same query is running from SQL builder section without any problem. The query was having LIMIT at the end. I have also tried without LIMIT option. But none of the queries are working from the datasource section. But infact the same query is working fine from SQL builder section. But the exception is happening only while running the test step. Si i think this could be a bug.

Comment: yeah sounds like it..You should log it in soapUIs blog.